# Existence of declination at one part in the intersection of two planes

Tags: c++, 3d, intersection, point-cloud-library, ransac

I would like to compute the intersection line of two planes. The planes were detected by RANSAC algorithm. The intersection line was found, using the class of PCL library,   "planeWithPlaneIntersection" ([planeWithPlaneIntersection_class_PCL](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/intersections_8h_source.html)). Also, the planes are neither perpendicular nor vertical. Moreover, the vector of the intersection line is computed by the cross product, is that ok for the intersection of non-perpendicular/vertical planes??? The output of the intersection is a line which at one part has a declination from the two planes, as you can see in the following image [plane_intersection_PCL_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3DAW.png)
Furthermore, i made changes at the RANSAC's threshold and the problem remains! Also, the declination is bigger than RANSAC's threshold!
I don't understand the existence of declination from two planes. Any comment would be valuable!!!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are talking about two issues: Finding a plane-plane intersection, and finding a plane using ransac. I would guess the plane-plane intersection in pcl is just fine. Your image is not very clear to me. I would expect ransac to return not quite the perfect plane of local points and be biased a bit towards the other plane?

Comment: I used ransac in order to detect the planes and after that, i found the intersection of two planes. The intersection line has a problem, she doesn't lie over the two planes but she has a declination from these, as you can see in the new image that i have attached. I can't understand why this occurs.

Comment: I don' know if this declination for some reason is justified.